# Causal Impact package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to using the following method

https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html

The author gives the code to install the Causal Impact package but I get the following error

> devtools::install_github("google/CausalImpact")
>   Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
>     Timeout was reached

I am using the latest version of R Studio and the latest version of R (3.3.1). I've not found anywhere how to get it to install so any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that the biggest problem about using this method is dependencies installation. The *R* package `bsts` has to be installed, whereas its latest version is not compatible with windows machines (linux only).

Thereby you need to install a previous one:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/bsts_0.6.2.zip", 
                 repos = NULL, type = "local")
```

Comment: Please, have a look at [editing in markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

For me this works

```
library(httr)
set_config(use_proxy(url="x.x.x.x",port=8080,username="xxxxx",password="****")) 
options(download.file.method = "wininet")
```